# R cannot be resolved to a variable on newly installed eclipse

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-juno

I have been looking for this on stack overflow for the past two hours and have tried a lot of things but nothing worked.

I have installed eclipse juno just this morning and i am getting this error `R cannot be resolved to a variable` in any project that I create. Also, I cannot see any files under the gen folder, even after I build the project. I have tried clean project, installed `ia32 libs` for my 64 bit system running ubuntu, tried changing folder positions, rebooting system but nothing worked.

The generated code is:

```
package tanvi.alarm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tanvi.alarm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10486659/1289716

Comment: Similar issue faced by others. This thread may help too [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: i had already read these threads..tried a lot of things..did not work..any further help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have this line

```
import android.R;
```

and if, remove it and clean and build project again.

Same thing is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250135/missing-package-in-gen-folder-with-r-in-android/11250175#11250175). Check my answer.

Comment: clean project and build it again. if it won't help, create new project and copy all files to it.

Comment: in fact, i did not put anything at all in the generated files, still i have this error

Comment: so reinstall eclipse and SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you but in Windows, and I found a solution to it.

You have to check your **SDK's folder permissions**. I moved my SDK folder, which is located in my second HDD, to a new folder and it all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading to Juno, I had this problem.  It was fixed by using the Android SDK Manager to install Android SDK Build-tools.

Answer (score 2):

I've just spent a day finding a fix for this problem.

In my case I started with Eclipse: Help->Check for Updates. These updated and I then opened the SDK manager and updated a few packages there too.

After that I had the 'R cannot be resolved error' for new projects and also the 'Could not find *.apk' in other projects

My solution was to Help->Check for Updates in Eclipse again and then open the SDK manager again and a small number of extra packages were available for an update. These updates were not available the first time I looked for updates.

I restarted Eclipse after the 2nd round of update and all was fine after that.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing above is resolved then check your `/res` folder where there might be an error in xml file. Due to this error `R.Java` file will not be updated due to which the above problem might occur. If have the error in xml file it must be probably in `res-values-strings.xml`. Try removing that error and also update your Androidmanifest.xml if any string values are used.

This will automatically resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Juno myself yesterday and had to faff around in the beginning but everything seems to be  working now.  You didn;t say which SDK you've installed, but I'm assuming you are using the latest SDK (r20) as you seem to have dotted all the other Is. However, as r20 is the only version that currently works with Juno it would be best to check if you're unsure.

Unsurprisingly the code you supplied in the question works as is, so the problem isn't there. However, if there is an error in one of the XML files in that you have supplied, you'll need fix those before the `R` class can be generated.

Alternatively, if you previously had a 3.x version of Eclipse installed are you still using the same workspace for for running Juno?  If so I suggest starting again in a fresh workspace and see if you have the same issues. Even using `-clean` on the old workspace won't cut it.  If you want to keep using the old workspace directory, delete the *.metadata* directory within it and try again, though you will need to import any existing projects afterwards.

To be honest, I'd be surprised if it was a workspace clash as I'd expect you to have more problems that just an *R cannot be resolved* error, but I'm just trying to cover the bases.

Comment: Chilledrat Thanks a lot for your answer. But I had my problem solved, thanks to a lot of forums here on stackoverflow. Had to do a couple of things, there was this library i had to download and install, and then clicking on the Build Automatically option helped.

Comment: @tanvi - Cool, glad you got it sorted.  You should consider adding your own answer detailing the steps you went through to fix it.  It may help someone else in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had to install this library on my ubuntu 12.04, `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` (my system is 64 bit).
And on restart of eclipse, the files were generated.

If the problem persists, check if the `Project -> Build Automatically` is selected. Once selected, the project should run fine.